ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ttkbootstrap'
When trying to import ttkbootstrap and build the python, I just get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ttkbootstrap'

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk


Can't figure out what's going on. Help would be appreciated with a brief explanation, need to learn for future.
EDIT: FIXED

It is not clear when you get such error.  During building (do you mean building executable by PyInstaller?)? Or when running the generated executable?

yes, sorry when i go to build it

Cannot reproduce issue using PyInstaller 6.6.0 and Python 3.12.3 in Windows 11.

This is likely due to ttkbootstrap not being installed. To fix this, run
pip install ttkbootstrap

in command prompt
(win + r -> write "cmd" -> click enter)

I have both ttkbootstrap and pillow installed and when running pip show for both they return as installed. (using sublime, but tried VS too)

Try building as an administrator. That has been an error for me before
